# Relational Mapping of finite tree with instances

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, data-modeling, hierarchical-data

I have to represent the following structure in a relational database.
There are five hierarchy levels: *A*, *B*, *C*, *D*.
The relation between the hierarchy levels is always one to many,
so *A* has many *B*, but every *B* belongs to one certain *A*.
The same applies for *B*, *C*, *D*, *E*.
So far *B* has *A* as foreign key, *C* has *B* as foreign key and so forth.

```
A          1
         / |
B       1  2
      / |  |
C    1  2  3 
    /|  |  |
D  1 2  3  4
```

Where things get complicated is that I have to represent instances 
from *B* downwards. For one certain *B* I can have many different instances.
All instances have different data but the same tree structure below.

Let's say I have `MyB` with instance `fo` and instance `ba`.
Now `fo` and `ba` have to have the same number of children, and their 
children have to have the same number of children too.
In one instance the children will have certain values in the other instance
different values, but the sub-trees have the same structure.

As there can be many *B* there can be many sub-tree structures, but the
depth of the tree is always limited to four.

```
A          1
         / |  \
B       1  2fo 2ba 
      / |   |   |
C    1  2   3   4 
    /|  |   |\  |\
D  1 2  3   4 5 6 7
```

If `2fo` has one child and two grandchildren `2ba` also has to have one child and
two grandchildren.

**How do I cleanly map this structure in a relational database?**

**EDIT**

To answer [X-Zeros question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831149/relational-mapping-of-finite-tree-with-instances#comment15730341_11831149)  in more detail than is possible in the comments.
If someone adds a node to C2 and then to C3 the result has to look like this:

```
A          1--------
         / |       |
B       1  2fo    2ba 
      / |   |      |
C    1  2   3----  4----
    /|  |   |\  |  |\  |
D  1 2  3   4 5 9  6 7 10
```

Comment: Are the number of children known ahead of time, or are you just attempting to balance the tree?  What's supposed to happen if someone adds a new 'bottom' child record?  Also, what RDBMS (although with 5 levels, this isn't terrible otherwise...)

Comment: @podiluska: Oracle 10g, I'm interested in a clean table structure not so much in a specific implementation.

Comment: @X-Zero: The number of children is not known ahead of time and the tree doesn't need to be balanced. Second question is a very good one: If a new child is added, all instances will have to have a child added.

Comment: So, what's supposed to happen?  Do you have something adding auto-generated (missing) 'child' nodes, or is this a check-constraint (throw error if not 'correct')?  Why doesn't B1 have to match the '2' series?  And generally, all clarifications to questions in comments are supposed to trigger modifications to the original question, especially as comments get collapsed after a while.

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchical structure will be represented in a table via parentId. 
ParentId is the self referencing foreign key.

You can write a recursive query to pick the level B.

There will be more than one node at the level 2, 
in your example you enumerate nodes in each node as (1,2,4,etc ). 
In the real database example, you will know the nodeId.
ie: table can be like   table_ABCDE ( nodeId, letterRep, parentId )

How to represent the instances under level B:
Create an other table to keep the root of the instances from concept. 
create table instances ( id , instance_from_node , name )
ie: (444, B2, 2fo )
instance_from_node is foreign key to table_ABCDE nodeId

Algorithm how to add a new instance:
0- mark in the main tree (table_ABCDE) the B2 as a template.

1- check table instances table for the given node 
ie: 2fo ;  if 2fo is not already in the instances table , 
first add 2fo  (444, B2, 2fo ), 
then add 2ba   (445, B2, 2Ba )

2- insert all the new nodes to the table_ABCDE. All the new nodes mean node 2fo and all the nodes below.

In case of any addition/deletion, find the B-level parent, and apply the same change to all the instances from that level. To find the B-level parent also use the instances table in order to see that 2fo and 2ba are both driven from B2.

If you create an instance from 2fo, you need to check instances table, you will see that 2fo is instance of B2, you actually creating an instance from B2. And you will enter that instance also as B2's instance.